# Error in names(classes) <- clean_terms(names(classes)), 'names' attribute must be the same length as the vector

Tags: r

I am running a probit model for statistics.

```
probit <- glm(fine ~ mphover + age + female + cdl + outtown + statepol + budget_issue, data=speed, family=binomial(link="probit"))
```

And I wanted to calculate margins like here
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/margins.pdf or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html#interactions_in_logit

But I run into this error in several datasets when running margins(). Nothing seems to help so far. Tried manually deleting 'names' attributes. Re-did all calculations and now I'm just stuck.

```
> margins(probit, type="response")
Error in names(classes) <- clean_terms(names(classes)) : 
  'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

Here is traceback() if that helps:

```
4: find_terms_in_model.default(model, variables = variables)
3: find_terms_in_model(model, variables = variables)
2: margins.glm(probit, type = "response")
1: margins(probit, type = "response")
```

Comment: Oh my god. It worked. Thank you! 

I am still learning R and used $ to quickly pick variables from data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Thank you!

Turns out using `speed$fine`, etc. when I have already defined the dataset using `data=speed` is not needed and causes this error.

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean since `speed$fine` does not seem to be in the code in your question...

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and solved it by converting my data (which was imported from a .csv file) to a data frame from a tibble and making sure the variable names in the data frame were consistent with the call to glm.